# How can I make a SQL query that selects all rows matching a certain string then weights them based on the number of matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, sql-order-by

How can I create an SQL query that matches multiple strings with the `LIKE` operator, then `ORDERS` results by the number of matches it gets?

Also, is there a way to then store the number of matches, so that I can later do other calculations with that number in PHP?

I'm currently working with this code from another Stack Overflow answer

```
SELECT searchtopics_topicid, searchtopics_content FROM searchtopics 
    WHERE searchtopics_content
         LIKE '%string1%' OR searchtopics_content 
         LIKE '%string2%' OR searchtopics_content
         LIKE '%string3%' 
    ORDER BY 
         case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' then 1 else 0 end + 
         case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' then 1 else 0 end + 
         case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' then 1 else 0 end 
    DESC
```

Comment: I'm wondering if a free-text search package is what you need - have a look at Lucene, Sphinx and ElasticSearch (I should think there are several more of these).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code looks like it should work just fine, to store the number you'd just add the `ORDER BY` case logic to the select list.

```
SELECT searchtopics_topicid
     , searchtopics_content 
     , case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' then 1 else 0 end + 
       case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' then 1 else 0 end + 
       case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' then 1 else 0 end AS hit_ct 
FROM searchtopics 
WHERE searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' 
   OR searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' 
   OR searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' 
ORDER BY 
     case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' then 1 else 0 end + 
     case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' then 1 else 0 end + 
     case when searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' then 1 else 0 end 
DESC
```

In MySQL you can simplify this all a bit:

```
    SELECT searchtopics_topicid
         , searchtopics_content 
         , searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' 
           + searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' 
           + searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' AS hit_ct 
    FROM searchtopics 
    WHERE searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' 
        + searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' 
        + searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' > 0
    ORDER BY searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%' 
           + searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%' 
           + searchtopics_content LIKE '%string3%' DESC
```

Comment: sorry- I just added something to describe my problem a bit more- Is there a way to take the word count that the SQL query calculates and pass that on to a PHP statement?

Comment: I'm pretty much only helpful on the sql portion, don't know much about PHP.

Comment: what does the `then 1 else 0 end` thing do? If I change the value to, let's say, `then 10 else 0 end`, will that `10` make that case statement be weighed heavier relative to the others?

Comment: Exactly right,  the bottom query each comparison `searchtopics_content LIKE '%string2%'` will return `1` if it matches, or `0` if it doesn't, so adding them together will get you the number of matches.  The `CASE` statement is like an `IF..THEN`, if it matches then `1` otherwise `0`, if you wanted to weight them you could change the `1` and `0` in the top query, or multiply the bottom query by some weight, ie: `searchtopics_content LIKE '%string1%'*3`

Comment: ok yeah thanks- i think i can use that to get what i had wanted originall